# Ubuntu 23.04 working fine on Kernel 5.19.0 but no WiFi, no Ethernet, no dual monitor support, no bluetooth and a lot more issues on 6.2.0-20

Tags: wireless, kernel, bluetooth, ethernet, monitor

Whenever I try to boot with default kernel version in my laptop from grub which is 6.2.0 I do not get any internet - no options to turn on WiFi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, USB tethering also does notw work, I cannot use external monitor. There are no animations and the quick settings menu only has the power mode and the dark style mode option rest have disappeared. However when I boot into ubuntu with 5.19.0-40 it works perfectly fine with no issues in anything.

I had some software updates (not OS updates just simple software ones) which I had left to be installed and had gone afk but when I came back my laptop was not on and on booting up I encountered this issue.

EDIT : Also if possible can someone explain how can I set 5.19.0 as my default kernel that boots up when I select ubuntu in grub. I have already followed the guide where the default selected option is the Advanced options but I would like to make it so that whenever I select ubuntu in grub it by defaults boots into 5.19.0 instead of me having to select the option in advanced options for ubuntu.

Comment: This morning I applyed security updated from kernel 6.2.0.20 for 6.2.0.20+2 and NVIDIA driver 525. After boot, all network is disabled! Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth not exist and Config App dont allow add devices. Monitor is 1024p and not allow change. Gnome change from Wayland to Xorg x11. All S.O. configuration was losted and without Internet I cant apply fix updates.

Comment: @FernandoSantucci yes now that you mention it the software updates that I was talking about in my question were mostly nvidia based I believe. Did you try booting through 5.19.0 because that is working fine for me.

Comment: For my UEFI boot of Ubuntu 23.04, the key to start Grub Menu changed from ESC to SHIFT+ESC. Just ESC brought me to Grub CLI prompt. Solved this problem, I noted that new Kernel of security update was from Oracle, not Kernel Generic. I think Canonical team screwed things. On Grub Menu I choose the previous Kernel 6.2.0.20 Generic and all work fine to me. Then update the NVIDIA driver from 525 to 530 and remove the Kernel 5.19 from Ubuntu 22.10. I dont edit /etc/default/grub yet to set the Kernel 6.2.0.20 Generic as permanent. Next run update-grub.